# Issue with setting up simple AngularJS MVC

Tags: angularjs

I have set up a AngularJS MVC structure. Unfortunately, there is no specific errors or warnings in the script. However, the screen is displaying nothing and views is not redering according to the URLS give in the address bar.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Please see the below codes sepearate

-----------------controller.js---------------------

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
var controllers = {};
demoApp.controller('simpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        name: 'Rex',
        city: 'Kensas'
    }, {
        name: 'Cyrin',
        city: 'Texas'
    }, {
        name: 'Vijith',
        city: 'Florida'
    }];
    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push({
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
        $scope.newCustomer.name = '';
        $scope.newCustomer.city = '';
    };
});
demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            controller: 'simpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            controller: 'simpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/view1'
        });
});
```

-----------------------index.html--------------------------

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div ng-view=""></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

-------------Partials/view1.html----------------------------

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name }}</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    User Name:<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br />
    User Name:<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <br />
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br />
    <a href="#view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

Not including view2.html as it is less important here.

Hoping for the quick fix. :)

Thanks for your time!
Rex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Angular you are using?

If you are using 1.2* then you have to explicitly inject `ngRoute` module into your app by including `angular-route.js` separately

See docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module

1. Import `ngRoute` in your code

   ```
   var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
   ```
2. Also you have not defined your controller to any of your HTML elements.

   ```
   <div ng-controller="simpleController"></div>
   ```

**[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/LkIKlQ9hb9HW836zZ9gW?p=preview)**

Note: Before you ask anything see your browser's console for any errors. If you haven't already included `ngRoute`, it throws an error you can see it in console.

Comment: Perfect help for me. The issue was really because of the ngRoute inclusion to the program. And It worked well without defining a controller to the page.

And I was wondering I noticed when we click on each view1 or view2 links the page is reloading. Is that normal with AngularJS. What I expected with a single page application means the page wont refresh while clicking on multiple links. Please advice!

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, angular applications are single-page when you use routing. The page won't refresh, only the content inside `ng-view` changes according to your router configuration

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your ng-controller

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have defined your app (ng-app).. But you have not defined your controller in any of your HTML files.

For the HTML file where you need to use the controller, call it there via:

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController">
    // The rest of your HTML
</div>
```